# Passing value through path using postback url

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am using a `datalist` on customer page to list all customers. There is a page named "view" where I want to show the details of the particular selected customer. Here is the image button code:

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetImageURL(Eval("image")) %>' PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("id", "view.aspx?id={0}") %>'/></tr>
```

`id` is the unique field of the customer table. Now how should I retrieve the customer data on `view.aspx`, using the particular ID passed from the customer page. I use this code but it's not working:

```
   Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM customer where id = @id", con)
    Int(ID = Request.QueryString("id"))
    con.Open()
    ProfileData.DataSource = mycommand.ExecuteReader 
    ProfileData.DataBind()
    con.Close()
```

I just want to do that. In the customer page all customers are displayed with their image and when I click on any one of them then the details of the particular customer should be displayed on view.aspx page ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using @id as CommandParameter to add this `id` as value to command parameter..
as

```
Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM customer where id = @id", con)
   mycommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int)
        mycommand.Parameters("@id").Value = Convert.ToInt32( Request.QueryString("id"))

    con.Open()
    ProfileData.DataSource = mycommand.ExecuteReader 
    ProfileData.DataBind()
    con.Close()
```

check these link to know about the parameter..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx